# Save record on button click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, wrapper-class, aura-iteration

I have a list of records displayed on lightning component using

There are Save buttons corresponding to each record. The fields of the records are editable. I want to save the record, the corresponding button of which has been clicked. Other records will not be saved. I would like to understand, how to save this particular record. I am very new to lightning and any sample code  would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is very similar to the app project on Salesforce TrailHead - [Build a Lightning App with the Lightning Design System](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/slds-lightning-components-workshop)

The idea is to split the task into two components:
- List - will hold the list of records
- Editor - will hold data about specific record and allow you to save it

The following is general approach:

1. `List` would get list of records from Apex controller on `init` even handler
2. `List` would iterate over the list of records and display `Editor` component for each record
3. `Editor` would have a form with a save button
4. Clicking save button on `Editor` form would call Apex controller to save data